# Cannot run dev on nextjs nodemon

Tags: next.js, nodemon

I'm using nodemon with the following configuration in `nodemon.json`.

```
{
    "verbose": true,
    "ignore": ["node_modules", ".next", "app/"],
    "watch": ["app.js"] 
}
```

I'm using [this booilerplate](https://github.com/MustansirZia/next-express-bootstrap-boilerplate) with follwing configuration in `package.json`.

```
"build": "cd app && next build",
"start": "npm run build && env NODE_ENV=production node app.js -p >$PORT",
"learn": "npm run build && env NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
"dev": "nodemon -w app.js app.js"
```

Once I run `npm run dev`, I'm getting following output.

```
Using "webpackDevMiddleware" config function defined in
next.config.js. Using external babel configuration Location:
"/home/shintaro/Desktop/projects/frontend/app/.babelrc"
```

and the server never starts...